# Arrow function within jQuery map

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrow-functions, map-function

I'm trying to use an arrow function within jQuery's `map` function. With the following titlesText is the correct length but each string is empty:

```
let titles = $(panelBody).find('h4');
let titlesText = $(titles).map(title => $(title).text());
```

My ES6 transpiling is working, and jQuery is working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/map/

The first argument to jQuery map is the index.

```
let testTitlesText = $(testTitles).map((index, testTitle) => $(testTitle).text());
```

Also as just a side note, you could use `testTitle.innerText` in the map to avoid creating a new jQuery object for each map invocation.

```
//testTitles is already a jQuery object, and you can use innerText
let testTitlesText = testTitles.map((index, testTitle) => testTitle.innerText);
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks Taplar u rock. I'll mark answered as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: Also I decided to just use vanilla js map: testTitlesText = $(testTitles).get().map(testTitle => testTitle.innerText);